# Unable to parse Measurement Protocol JSON payload

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to send a post payload however I was returned an error, can advise?
`tracking_id` is the id that I am using.

```
url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect"
        payload = {
        "v": 1,
        "tid": tracking_id,
        "cid": 555,
        "t": "event",
        "ec": "download",
        "ea": "file_download",
        "el": data['file_name'],
        "ev": 1,
        "cd5": data['hash']
        }

        response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
        print(response.text)
```

**Error message**

```
{
  "validationMessages": [ {
    "description": "Unable to parse Measurement Protocol JSON payload. invalid JSON in google.analytics.measurement.Measurement,  near 1:1 (offset  0): unexpected character: 'v'; expected  '{'",
    "validationCode": "VALUE_INVALID"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tracking_id` is used if you use Universal Analytics. But your API call is sending request to GA Measurement Protocol which means you are using Google Analytics 4. `tracking_id` is not accepted by GA4.

For GA4, you need to provide `measurement_id` and `api_secret`.

Here is an example code that should work for you:

```
const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const api_secret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY',
    events: [{
      name: 'Download',
      params: {
        "ea": "file_download",
        "el": data['file_name'],
        "ev": 1,
        "cd5": data['hash'],
        "and": "whatever you wish..."
      }
    }]
  })
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

If you don't get any error in `debug` mode, change the URL from

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/mp/collect
```

to

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect
```

and the events should get displayed in GA4 realtime events section.

**These references might be helpful:**

1. [Universal Analytics is going away](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en)
2. [Sending events using GA4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag)

Comment: Noted, how to I retrieve the custom event parameter from the reporting tools?

Comment: Hi there, this is a client side code, is there a server side code?

Comment: I recently tried again, it gives me the following parameter

HTTP/2 204 No Content

Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 03:30:18 GMT

Pragma: no-cache

Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Last-Modified: Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT

Content-Type: text/plain

Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin

Server: Golfe2

Content-Length: 0

Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

Comment: I'm trying to setup that here, /debug returns { validationMessages: [] }, but when using /mp I can't see events logged in realtime. Is there some other setup to do ? Actually nevermind... Setting measurementId, or api_secret to something absurd yields the same outcome... So something is definitely wrong.